# Schduling in Blueprism doesn't start

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, blueprism

I am working on Blueprism v6.8.0 and i am trying to schedul a process

[image]

But it doesn't work ? I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you're directly connected to a "local database", which would seem to imply you're running your environment without an Application Server component.

Scheduling only works when using an Application Server. This is clearly defined in the Blue Prism documentation:

> The scheduler runs within a Blue Prism Server service. It is a background process which waits for the next schedule activation time and then executes any schedules due to run at that time.

<sup>Source: [Scheduler | Blue Prism Help](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-8/en-us/helpScheduler.htm?Highlight=schedule)</sup>

If you need this functionality, you'll need to set up and configure the Blue Prism Server component/service to execute schedules per the steps on [Scheduler configuration | Blue Prism Help](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-8/en-us/helpSystemManagerScheduler.htm?Highlight=server%20schedule).